# Using a Twig variable inside a Symfony translation in a template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, translation

It is getting late and I think my mind is shutting down...for the life of me I cannot work out how to change the translation key to work with the value of `currentType`.

```
{% set currentType = site.getCurrentType() %}
{{ 'messages.site.{currentType}'|trans({ '%url%' : path('appbundle_course_url', { 'subdomain': site.subdomain }) }) }}
```

I'm doing something derpy and will kick myself when I see the solution. I just know it.

Comment: `'messages.site.'~currentType` ?

Comment: @DOZ Thanks, I had tried that. It does concat the string together but it doesn't translate. I'm left with an output of `messages.site.typenamehere'. (Yep, i've cleared the Symfony cache and double and triple checked the translation)...

Comment: simple question : if you put the correct value directly instead of Twig variable, does translation works (just to be sure)  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOZ hint was actually almost correct.

```
'messages.site.'~currentType|trans
```

means translate currentType then append to string (Filter is applied first).
So proper braces do the trick.

This works in my Code:

```
{{ ('messages.site.'~currentType)|trans({ '%url%' : path('appbundle_course_url', { 'subdomain': site.subdomain }) }) }}
```